# How to write interactive geometry applets with Python

Tags: python

I am interested in writing interactive applets in Computational Geometry using Python.  For starters I would like to code up an applet like [this](http://www-cgrl.cs.mcgill.ca/~godfried/teaching/cg-projects/97/Thierry/thierry507webprj/507applet/triangulize.html) one or [this](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/ctk/Pick.shtml) one, in which the user 'mouses in' points and a certain computation is performed.

The reason I ask this is because, I am familiar with Python and being a scripting language I guess it would be easier(and shorter) to write applets in Python rather than Java, a language in which I don't have any experience.

Are there any standard set of libraries to write such applets in Python?

Comment: This post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*